# Vue3 Pinia Store: Uncaught TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, pinia

I am using Vite(Vue.js3) with Typescript and with Pinia for store.

this is my auth.ts pinia store file:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { onBeforeUnmount } from 'vue';
interface AuthState {
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    username: string | null;
    email: string | null;
    roles: string[];
    firstname: string | null;
    lastname: string | null;
    jwtToken: string | null;
    tokenRefreshIntervalId: NodeJS.Timer | null;
}

export const useAuthStore = defineStore('auth', {
    state: (): AuthState => ({
        isAuthenticated: false,
        username: null,
        email: null,
        roles: [],
        firstname: null,
        lastname: null,
        jwtToken: null,
        tokenRefreshIntervalId: null,
    }),

    getters: {
        isAuthenticated: (state: AuthState) => state.isAuthenticated,
        getUsername: (state: AuthState) => state.username,
        getEmail: (state: AuthState) => state.email,
        getRoles: (state: AuthState) => state.roles,
        getFirstname: (state: AuthState) => state.firstname,
        getLastname: (state: AuthState) => state.lastname,
    },

    actions: {
        async login(username: string, password: string) {
            try {
                const response = await axios.post('/auth/login', {
                    username,
                    password,
                });
                const token = response.data.user.access_token;
                const decodedToken = jwt_decode(token);
                console.log(decodedToken);
                this.username = decodedToken.username || null;
                this.email = decodedToken.email || null;
                this.roles = decodedToken.roles || [];
                this.firstname = decodedToken.firstname || null;
                this.lastname = decodedToken.lastname || null;
                this.isAuthenticated = true;
                this.autoLogout();
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Failure:', error);
            }
        },

        logout() {
            this.isAuthenticated = false;
            this.username = null;
            this.email = null;
            this.roles = [];
            this.firstname = null;
            this.lastname = null;
            this.clearTokenRefresh();
        },

        async validateToken() {
            try {
                await axios.get('/auth/validate', {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.jwtToken}`,
                    },
                });
                return true;
            } catch (error) {
                this.logout();
                return false;
            }
        },

        autoLogout() {
            const tokenRefreshInterval = 10 * 60 * 1000;

            const refreshToken = async () => {
                try {
                    if (this.isAuthenticated && !(await this.validateToken())) {
                        this.logout();
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            };
            this.tokenRefreshIntervalId = setInterval(
                refreshToken,
                tokenRefreshInterval,
            );
            onBeforeUnmount(() => {
                if (this.tokenRefreshIntervalId) {
                    clearInterval(this.tokenRefreshIntervalId);
                }
            });
        },

        clearTokenRefresh() {
            if (this.tokenRefreshIntervalId) {
                clearInterval(this.tokenRefreshIntervalId);
            }
        },

        hasRole(role: string) {
            return this.roles.includes(role);
        },
    },
});
```

and this is my Login.vue file:

```
<template>
    <div class="account-pages my-5 pt-sm-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body p-4">
                            <div class="text-center mt-2">
                                <h5 class="text-primary">Prijava</h5>
                                <p class="text-muted"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="p-2 mt-4">
                                <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="username">username</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" v-model="username" required placeholder="Enter username" autocomplete="username" v-focus>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" v-model="password" required placeholder="Enter password" autocomplete="current-password">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="mt-3 text-end">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary w-sm waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Login</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
  
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { useAuthStore } from '../stores/auth';
import { useToast } from 'vue-toastification';

const username = ref('');
const password = ref('');
const error = ref('');
const authStore = useAuthStore();
const router = useRouter();
const route = useRoute();
const toast = useToast();

async function handleSubmit() {
    try {
        await authStore.login(username.value, password.value);
        router.push(route.query.redirect?.toString() || '/');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
</script>
```

The problem is that whenever I want to login I get this error:

> TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'isAuthenticated'

Why I cant set "isAuthenticated" but I can set other things like username,email,roles,... and how can I fix this ? The data is decoded successfully in my `console.log(decodedToken);` so I know the response is not null.

Comment: Because isAuthenticated getter name clashes with state property. Those getters are redundant. If you want a property to be writable, you don't need a getter

Comment: oh I didn't know that getters are redundant if I want property to be writable. Thanks for explanation